# GDB with Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, gdb, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

When I try to run my C++ hello world program in Eclipse, I get the error "Error while launching command: gdb --version".

SO won't let me upload the following screenshot: [Screenshot 1](http://f.cl.ly/items/06132N1j3O2E0b42002R/Image%202012-02-15%20at%205.37.00%20PM.png)

I'm running eclipse on Windows 7 and using Cygwin's GCC/GDB. Typing gdb --version in cygwin causes no problems. I've confirmed that it's in C:/cygwin/bin. This path is added as an environment variable. What's the problem?

Here's a screenshot of my path variable: [Screenshot 2](http://f.cl.ly/items/1N07050S0B0S283d2D2L/Image%202012-02-15%20at%205.35.41%20PM.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is be because Eclipse CDT does not support gdb version 7.5.  Please try to install the gdb version 7.3, or older.